# Как подключить стили к layout в Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, css, razor, layout

У меня есть собственно созданный _LayoutIndex.cshtml, для страницы Index. Мне нужно подключить к нему стили ( *_LayoutIndex.cshtml.css*). Как это сделать?

Мой код в Layout

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Pages/Shared/_LayoutIndex.cshtml.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AAAAAA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Vtitdit.ISP20.Naumenko.AccountingOfServices.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@600,800&display=swap">

    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-page">
        <header>
            <div class="header-container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ms-5 navbar-light mb-3">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Лого типа</a>
                    <a class="nav_element nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Index">Главная</a>
                    <a class="nav_element nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Informations/Employees">Преподаватели</a>
                    <a class="nav_element nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/ServiseInfo/Services">Специальности</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main role="main">
            <div class="main-text text-lg-start lh-1  align-middle">
                @RenderBody()
                <p>Учёт</p>
                <p>Предоставляемых</p>
                <p>Услуг</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>


    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать следующий код для подключения стилей. Также не забудьте обновить страницу используя комбинацию клавиш **SHIFT+F5**:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Pages/Shared/_LayoutIndex.cshtml.css")" />`